# Issue removing date when tuning hyperparameters in XGB model

Tags: r, machine-learning, tidymodels, recipe

I'm following this fantastic [blog](https://blog.bguarisma.com/time-series-forecasting-lab-part-2-feature-engineering-with-recipes) as I try to understand how to model multiple time series using multiple models in R.

I've received an error when running my hyperparameter tuning for my XGB model using Tidymodels, see the error below.

[image]

My data contains a variable called Month but I believe I've removed it from the model using step_rm(Month) in my workflow.

```
# XGBOOST WORKFLOW
tic()
wflw_fit_xgboost <- workflow() %>%
  add_model(
    spec = boost_tree(
      mode = "regression"
    ) %>%
      set_engine("xgboost")
  ) %>%
  add_recipe(recipe_spec %>% step_rm(Month)) %>%
  fit(training(splits))
toc()
```

The code runs successfully until the tune_grid of the XGB model near line 839 where the error occurs.

How can I successfully remove/handle Month from the model? From my research I don't believe update_role works for Date fields.

Here is a copy of my scripts so far...

```
# LOAD PACKAGES -----------------------------------------------------------

if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(
  tidyverse,
  timetk,
  tsibble,
  tsibbledata,
  fastDummies,
  skimr,
  recipes,
  tidymodels,
  modeltime,
  tictoc,
  future,
  doFuture,
  plotly,
  modeltime.ensemble
)

# LOAD DATA
aus_retail_tbl <- tsibbledata::aus_retail %>%
  timetk::tk_tbl()

# FILTER FOR SPECIFIC STATES
monthly_retail_tbl <- aus_retail_tbl %>%
  filter(State == "Australian Capital Territory") %>%
  mutate(Month = as.Date(Month)) %>%
  mutate(Industry = as_factor(Industry)) %>%
  select(Month, Industry, Turnover)

monthly_retail_tbl

myskim <- skim_with(numeric = sfl(max, min), append = TRUE)

Industries <- unique(monthly_retail_tbl$Industry)

# CREATE FEATURE ENGINEERING TABLE ----------------------------------------

groups <- lapply(X = 1:length(Industries), FUN = function(x) {
  monthly_retail_tbl %>%
    filter(Industry == Industries[x]) %>%
    arrange(Month) %>%
    mutate(Turnover = log1p(x = Turnover)) %>%
    mutate(Turnover = standardize_vec(Turnover)) %>%
    future_frame(Month, .length_out = "12 months", .bind_data = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(Industry = Industries[x]) %>%
    tk_augment_fourier(.date_var = Month, .periods = 12, .K = 1) %>%
    tk_augment_lags(.value = Turnover, .lags = c(12, 13)) %>%
    tk_augment_slidify(
      .value = c(Turnover_lag12, Turnover_lag13),
      .f = ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE),
      .period = c(3, 6, 9, 12),
      .partial = TRUE,
      .align = "center"
    )
})

# IMPUTE MISSING VALUES FOR THE LAGGED AND ROLLING LAG PREDICTORS
groups_fe_tbl <- bind_rows(groups) %>%
  rowid_to_column(var = "rowid") %>%
  group_by(Industry) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Turnover_lag12:Turnover_lag13_roll_12), .funs = ts_impute_vec, period = 12) %>%
  ungroup()

tmp <- monthly_retail_tbl %>%
  group_by(Industry) %>%
  arrange(Month) %>%
  mutate(Turnover = log1p(x = Turnover)) %>%
  group_map(~ c(
    mean = mean(.x$Turnover, na.rm = TRUE),
    sd = sd(.x$Turnover, na.rm = TRUE)
  )) %>%
  bind_rows()

std_mean <- tmp$mean

std_sd <- tmp$sd

rm("tmp")


# CREATE PREPARED AND FUTURE DATASETS -------------------------------------

# RETAIN THE ROWS WHERE THERE IS NO NA VALUES IN TURNOVER I.E. REMOVE THE FUTURE DATASET THAT WAS ADDED DURING FEATURE ENGINEERING
data_prepared_tbl <- groups_fe_tbl %>%
  filter(!is.na(Turnover)) %>%
  drop_na()

# RETAIN THE ROWS THAT WERE ADDED DURING FEATURE ENGINEERING
future_tbl <- groups_fe_tbl %>%
  filter(is.na(Turnover))


# CREATE THE TRAIN AND TEST DATASETS --------------------------------------

splits <- data_prepared_tbl %>%
  time_series_split(Month,
    assess = "86 months",
    cumulative = TRUE
  )

splits

splits %>%
  tk_time_series_cv_plan() %>%
  glimpse()


# CREATE PREPROCESSING RECIPES --------------------------------------------

recipe_spec <- recipe(Turnover ~ ., data = training(splits)) %>%
  update_role(rowid, new_role = "indicator") %>%
  step_other(Industry) %>%
  step_timeseries_signature(Month) %>%
  step_rm(matches("(.xts$)|(.iso$)|(hour)|(minute)|(second)|(day)|(week)|(am.pm)")) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal(), one_hot = TRUE) %>%
  step_normalize(Month_index.num, Month_year)

pre_norm <- recipe(Turnover ~ ., data = training(splits)) %>%
  step_timeseries_signature(Month) %>%
  prep() %>%
  juice() %>%
  myskim()

Month_index.num_limit_lower <- pre_norm %>%
  filter(skim_variable == "Month_index.num") %>%
  select(numeric.min)

Month_index.num_limit_upper <- pre_norm %>%
  filter(skim_variable == "Month_index.num") %>%
  select(numeric.max)

Month_year_limit_lower <- pre_norm %>%
  filter(skim_variable == "Month_year") %>%
  select(numeric.min)

Month_year_limit_upper <- pre_norm %>%
  filter(skim_variable == "Month_year") %>%
  select(numeric.max)

# SAVE FEATURE ENGINEERING ------------------------------------------------


feature_engineering_artifacts_list <- list(
  # DATA
  data = list(
    data_prepared_tbl = data_prepared_tbl,
    future_tbl = future_tbl,
    industries = Industries
  ),
  # RECIPES
  recipes = list(
    recipe_spec = recipe_spec
  ),
  # SPLITS
  splits = splits,
  # INVERSION PARAMETERS
  standardize = list(
    std_mean = std_mean,
    std_sd   = std_sd
  ),
  normalize = list(
    Month_index.num_limit_lower = Month_index.num_limit_lower,
    Month_index.num_limit_upper = Month_index.num_limit_upper,
    Month_year_limit_lower = Month_year_limit_lower,
    Month_year_limit_upper = Month_year_limit_upper
  )
)

feature_engineering_artifacts_list %>%
  write_rds("feature_engineering_artifacts_list.rds")


# LOAD ARTIFACTS ----------------------------------------------------------

artifacts <- read_rds("feature_engineering_artifacts_list.rds")

splits <- artifacts$splits
recipe_spec <- artifacts$recipes$recipe_spec
Industries <- artifacts$data$industries

# CREATE WORKFLOWS --------------------------------------------------------

# RANDOM FOREST WORKFLOW
tic()
wflw_fit_rf <- workflow() %>%
  add_model(
    spec = rand_forest(
      mode = "regression"
    ) %>%
      set_engine("ranger")
  ) %>%
  add_recipe(recipe_spec %>% step_rm(Month)) %>%
  fit(training(splits))
toc()

wflw_fit_rf

# XGBOOST WORKFLOW
tic()
wflw_fit_xgboost <- workflow() %>%
  add_model(
    spec = boost_tree(
      mode = "regression"
    ) %>%
      set_engine("xgboost")
  ) %>%
  add_recipe(recipe_spec %>% step_rm(Month)) %>%
  fit(training(splits))
toc()

wflw_fit_xgboost

# PROPHET WORKFLOW
tic()
wflw_fit_prophet <- workflow() %>%
  add_model(
    spec = prophet_reg(
      seasonality_daily  = FALSE,
      seasonality_weekly = FALSE,
      seasonality_yearly = TRUE
    ) %>%
      set_engine("prophet")
  ) %>%
  add_recipe(recipe_spec) %>%
  fit(training(splits))
toc()

wflw_fit_prophet

# PROPHET BOOST WORKFLOW
tic()
wflw_fit_prophet_boost <- workflow() %>%
  add_model(
    spec = prophet_boost(
      seasonality_daily  = FALSE,
      seasonality_weekly = FALSE,
      seasonality_yearly = FALSE
    ) %>%
      set_engine("prophet_xgboost")
  ) %>%
  add_recipe(recipe_spec) %>%
  fit(training(splits))
toc()

wflw_fit_prophet_boost


# MODELTIME TABLE ---------------------------------------------------------

submodels_tbl <- modeltime_table(
  wflw_fit_rf,
  wflw_fit_xgboost,
  wflw_fit_prophet,
  wflw_fit_prophet_boost
)

# CALIBRATION TABLE -------------------------------------------------------

calibrated_wflws_tbl <- submodels_tbl %>%
  modeltime_calibrate(new_data = testing(splits))

calibrated_wflws_tbl

calibrated_wflws_tbl %>%
  modeltime_accuracy(testing(splits)) %>%
  arrange(rmse)


# SAVE WORKFLOW -----------------------------------------------------------

workflow_artifacts <- list(
  workflows = list(
    wflw_random_forest = wflw_fit_rf,
    wflw_xgboost = wflw_fit_xgboost,
    wflw_prophet = wflw_fit_prophet,
    wflw_prophet_boost = wflw_fit_prophet_boost
  ),
  calibration = list(calibration_tbl = calibrated_wflws_tbl)
)

workflow_artifacts %>%
  write_rds("workflow_artifacts_list.rds")


# READ IN WORKFLOW ARTIFACTS ----------------------------------------------

wflw_artifacts <- read_rds("workflow_artifacts_list.rds")

wflw_artifacts$calibration$calibration_tbl %>%
  modeltime_accuracy(testing(splits)) %>%
  arrange(rmse)


# SET UP CROSS VALIDATION PLAN --------------------------------------------

set.seed(123)

resamples_kfold <- training(splits) %>%
  vfold_cv(v = 10)

# resamples_kfold %>%
#   tk_time_series_cv_plan() %>%
#   filter(Industry == Industries[1]) %>%
#   plot_time_series_cv_plan(.date_var = Month,
#                            .value = Turnover,
#                            .facet_ncol = 2)


# PROPHET BOOST PARAMETER TUNING -----------------------------------------

model_spec_prophet_boost_tune <- prophet_boost(
  mode = "regression",
  changepoint_num = tune(),
  seasonality_yearly = FALSE,
  seasonality_weekly = FALSE,
  seasonality_daily = FALSE,
  mtry = tune(),
  trees = tune(),
  min_n = tune(),
  tree_depth = tune(),
  learn_rate = tune(),
  loss_reduction = tune()
) %>%
  set_engine("prophet_xgboost")

wflw_spec_prophet_boost_tune <- workflow() %>%
  add_model(model_spec_prophet_boost_tune) %>%
  add_recipe(artifacts$recipes$recipe_spec)

wflw_spec_prophet_boost_tune

# artifacts$recipes$recipe_spec %>%
#   update_role(Month, new_role = "indicator") %>%
#   prep() %>%
#   summary() %>%
#   group_by(role) %>%
#   summarise(n=n())

# GRID SPECIFICATION - PROPHET BOOST

# ROUND 1

set.seed(123)
pb_grid_spec_1 <- grid_latin_hypercube(
  extract_parameter_set_dials(model_spec_prophet_boost_tune) %>%
    update(mtry = mtry(range = c(1, 49))),
  size = 20
)

pb_grid_spec_1

registerDoFuture()

plan(
  strategy = cluster,
  workers  = parallel::makeCluster(parallel::detectCores())
)

tic()
tune_results_prophet_boost_1 <- wflw_spec_prophet_boost_tune %>%
  tune_grid(
    resamples = resamples_kfold,
    grid = pb_grid_spec_1,
    control = control_grid(
      verbose = TRUE,
      allow_par = TRUE
    )
  )
toc()

plan(strategy = sequential)

# tune_results_prophet_boost_1 %>%
#   show_best("rmse", n = Inf)
#
# tune_results_prophet_boost_1 %>%
#   show_best("rsq", n = Inf)

pb_gr1 <- tune_results_prophet_boost_1 %>%
  autoplot() +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE)

ggplotly(pb_gr1)


# ROUND 2

set.seed(123)
pb_grid_spec_2 <- grid_latin_hypercube(
  extract_parameter_set_dials(model_spec_prophet_boost_tune) %>%
    update(
      mtry = mtry(range = c(1, 49)),
      learn_rate = learn_rate(range = c(-2.0, -1.0))
    ),
  size = 20
)

plan(
  strategy = cluster,
  workers  = parallel::makeCluster(parallel::detectCores())
)

tic()
tune_results_prophet_boost_2 <- wflw_spec_prophet_boost_tune %>%
  tune_grid(
    resamples = resamples_kfold,
    grid = pb_grid_spec_2,
    control = control_grid(
      verbose = TRUE,
      allow_par = TRUE
    )
  )
toc()

plan(strategy = sequential)

tune_results_prophet_boost_2 %>%
  show_best("rsq", n = 2)

tune_results_prophet_boost_2 %>%
  show_best("rmse", n = 2)

pb_gr2 <- tune_results_prophet_boost_2 %>%
  autoplot() +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE)

ggplotly(pb_gr2)

# ROUND 3 - FIXING TREE PARAMETER
set.seed(123)
pb_grid_spec_3 <- grid_latin_hypercube(
  extract_parameter_set_dials(model_spec_prophet_boost_tune) %>%
    update(
      mtry = mtry(range = c(1, 49)),
      learn_rate = learn_rate(range = c(-2.0, -1.0)),
      trees = trees(range = c(1500, 1770))
    ),
  size = 20
)

plan(
  strategy = cluster,
  workers  = parallel::makeCluster(parallel::detectCores())
)

tic()
tune_results_prophet_boost_3 <- wflw_spec_prophet_boost_tune %>%
  tune_grid(
    resamples = resamples_kfold,
    grid = pb_grid_spec_3,
    control = control_grid(
      verbose = TRUE,
      allow_par = TRUE
    )
  )
toc()

plan(strategy = sequential)

# tune_results_prophet_boost_3 %>%
#   show_best("rmse", n = 2)
#
# tune_results_prophet_boost_3 %>%
#   show_best("rsq", n = 2)

# SELECT THE BEST PROPHET BOOST MODEL
set.seed(123)
wflw_fit_prophet_boost_tuned <- wflw_spec_prophet_boost_tune %>%
  finalize_workflow(
    select_best(tune_results_prophet_boost_3, "rmse", n = 1)
  ) %>%
  fit(training(splits))

modeltime_table(wflw_fit_prophet_boost_tuned) %>%
  modeltime_calibrate(testing(splits)) %>%
  modeltime_accuracy()

# FIT THE ROUND 3 BEST PROPHET BOOST RSQ MODEL
set.seed(123)
wflw_fit_prophet_boost_tuned_rsq <- wflw_spec_prophet_boost_tune %>%
  finalize_workflow(
    select_best(tune_results_prophet_boost_3, "rsq", n = 1)
  ) %>%
  fit(training(splits))

modeltime_table(wflw_fit_prophet_boost_tuned_rsq) %>%
  modeltime_calibrate(testing(splits)) %>%
  modeltime_accuracy()

# SAVE PROPHET BOOST TUNING ARTIFACTS
tuned_prophet_xgboost <- list(
  # WORKFLOW SPEC
  tune_wkflw_spec = wflw_spec_prophet_boost_tune,
  # GRID SPEC
  tune_grid_spec = list(
    round1 = pb_grid_spec_1,
    round2 = pb_grid_spec_2,
    round3 = pb_grid_spec_3
  ),
  # TUNING RESULTS
  tune_results = list(
    round1 = tune_results_prophet_boost_1,
    round2 = tune_results_prophet_boost_2,
    round3 = tune_results_prophet_boost_3
  ),
  # TUNED WORKFLOW FIT
  tune_wflw_fit = wflw_fit_prophet_boost_tuned,
  # FROM FEATURE ENGINEERING
  splits = artifacts$splits,
  data = artifacts$data,
  recipes = artifacts$recipes,
  standardize = artifacts$standardize,
  normalize = artifacts$normalize
)

tuned_prophet_xgboost %>%
  write_rds("tuned_prophet_xgboost.rds")


# RANDOM FOREST PARAMETER TUNING -----------------------------------------
# ROUND 1
model_spec_random_forest_tune <- parsnip::rand_forest(
  mode = "regression",
  mtry = tune(),
  trees = 1000,
  min_n = tune()
) %>%
  set_engine("ranger")

wflw_spec_random_forest_tune <- workflow() %>%
  add_model(model_spec_random_forest_tune) %>%
  add_recipe(artifacts$recipes$recipe_spec)

wflw_spec_random_forest_tune

extract_parameter_set_dials(model_spec_random_forest_tune)

artifacts$recipes$recipe_spec %>%
  update_role(Month, new_role = "indicator") %>%
  prep() %>%
  summary() %>%
  group_by(role) %>%
  summarise(n = n())

set.seed(123)
rf_grid_spec_1 <- grid_latin_hypercube(
  extract_parameter_set_dials(model_spec_random_forest_tune) %>%
    update(mtry = mtry(range = c(1, 49))),
  size = 20
)

rf_grid_spec_1

plan(
  strategy = cluster,
  workers  = parallel::makeCluster(parallel::detectCores())
)

tic()
tune_results_random_forest_1 <- wflw_spec_random_forest_tune %>%
  tune_grid(
    resamples = resamples_kfold,
    grid = rf_grid_spec_1,
    control = control_grid(
      verbose = TRUE,
      allow_par = TRUE
    )
  )
toc()

plan(strategy = sequential)

tune_results_random_forest_1 %>%
  show_best("rmse", n = Inf)

tune_results_random_forest_1 %>%
  show_best("rsq", n = Inf)

rf_gr1 <- tune_results_random_forest_1 %>%
  autoplot() +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE)

ggplotly(rf_gr1)

# ROUND 2

set.seed(123)
rf_grid_spec_2 <- grid_latin_hypercube(
  extract_parameter_set_dials(model_spec_random_forest_tune) %>%
    update(mtry = mtry(range = c(17, 28))),
  size = 20
)

plan(
  strategy = cluster,
  workers  = parallel::makeCluster(parallel::detectCores())
)

tic()
tune_results_random_forest_2 <- wflw_spec_random_forest_tune %>%
  tune_grid(
    resamples = resamples_kfold,
    grid = rf_grid_spec_2,
    control = control_grid(
      verbose = TRUE,
      allow_par = TRUE
    )
  )
toc()

plan(strategy = sequential)

tune_results_random_forest_2 %>%
  show_best("rmse", n = Inf)

tune_results_random_forest_2 %>%
  show_best("rsq", n = Inf)

rf_gr2 <- tune_results_random_forest_2 %>%
  autoplot() +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE)

ggplotly(rf_gr2)

# FITTING ROUND 2 BEST RMSE MODEL
set.seed(123)
wflw_fit_random_forest_tuned <- wflw_spec_random_forest_tune %>%
  finalize_workflow(
    select_best(tune_results_random_forest_2, "rmse", n = 1)
  ) %>%
  fit(training(splits))

modeltime_table(wflw_fit_random_forest_tuned) %>%
  modeltime_calibrate(testing(splits)) %>%
  modeltime_accuracy()

# FITTING ROUND 2 BEST RSQ MODEL
set.seed(123)
wflw_fit_random_forest_tuned_rsq <- wflw_spec_random_forest_tune %>%
  finalize_workflow(
    select_best(tune_results_random_forest_2, "rsq", n = 1)
  ) %>%
  fit(training(splits))

modeltime_table(wflw_fit_random_forest_tuned_rsq) %>%
  modeltime_calibrate(testing(splits)) %>%
  modeltime_accuracy()

tuned_random_forest <- list(
  # WORKFLOW SPEC
  tune_wkflw_spec = wflw_spec_random_forest_tune,
  # GRIC SPEC
  tune_grid_spec = list(
    round1 = rf_grid_spec_1,
    round2 = rf_grid_spec_2
  ),
  # TUNING RESULTS
  tune_results = list(
    round1 = tune_results_random_forest_1,
    round2 = tune_results_random_forest_2
  ),
  # TUNED WORKFLOW FIT
  tune_wflw_fit = wflw_fit_random_forest_tuned,
  # FROM FEATURE ENGINEERING
  splits = artifacts$splits,
  data = artifacts$data,
  recipes = artifacts$recipes,
  standardize = artifacts$standardize,
  normalize = artifacts$normalize
)

tuned_random_forest %>%
  write_rds("tuned_random_forest.rds")


# PROPHET PARAMETER TUNING -----------------------------------------------

model_spec_prophet_tune <- prophet_reg(
  mode = "regression",
  growth = "linear",
  changepoint_num = tune(),
  changepoint_range = tune(),
  seasonality_yearly = TRUE,
  seasonality_weekly = FALSE,
  seasonality_daily = FALSE
) %>%
  set_engine("prophet")

wflw_spec_prophet_tune <- workflow() %>%
  add_model(model_spec_prophet_tune) %>%
  add_recipe(artifacts$recipes$recipe_spec)

wflw_spec_prophet_tune

# ROUND 1
set.seed(123)
prophet_grid_spec_1 <- grid_latin_hypercube(
  extract_parameter_set_dials(model_spec_prophet_tune) %>%
    update(
      changepoint_num = changepoint_num(range = c(0L, 50L), trans = NULL),
      changepoint_range = changepoint_range(range = c(0.7, 0.9), trans = NULL)
    ),
  size = 20
)

prophet_grid_spec_1

registerDoFuture()

plan(
  strategy = cluster,
  workers  = parallel::makeCluster(parallel::detectCores())
)

tic()
tune_results_prophet_1 <- wflw_spec_prophet_tune %>%
  tune_grid(
    resamples = resamples_kfold,
    grid = prophet_grid_spec_1,
    control = control_grid(
      verbose = TRUE,
      allow_par = TRUE
    )
  )
toc()

plan(strategy = sequential)

tune_results_prophet_1 %>%
  show_best("rmse", n = Inf)

tune_results_prophet_1 %>%
  show_best("rsq", n = Inf)

prophet_gr1 <- tune_results_prophet_1 %>%
  autoplot() +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE)

ggplotly(prophet_gr1)

# FITTING ROUND 1 BEST RMSE MODEL
set.seed(123)
wflw_fit_prophet_tuned <- wflw_spec_prophet_tune %>%
  finalize_workflow(
    select_best(tune_results_prophet_1, "rmse", n = 1)
  ) %>%
  fit(training(splits))

modeltime_table(wflw_fit_prophet_tuned) %>%
  modeltime_calibrate(testing(splits)) %>%
  modeltime_accuracy()

# FITTING ROUND 1 BEST RSQ MODEL
set.seed(123)
wflw_fit_prophet_tuned_rsq <- wflw_spec_prophet_tune %>%
  finalize_workflow(
    select_best(tune_results_prophet_1, "rsq", n = 1)
  ) %>%
  fit(training(splits))

modeltime_table(wflw_fit_prophet_tuned_rsq) %>%
  modeltime_calibrate(testing(splits)) %>%
  modeltime_accuracy()

tuned_prophet <- list(
  # WORKFLOW SPEC
  tune_wkflw_spec = wflw_spec_prophet_tune,
  # GRIC SPEC
  tune_grid_spec = list(
    round1 = prophet_grid_spec_1
  ),
  # TUNING RESULTS
  tune_results = list(
    round1 = tune_results_prophet_1
  ),
  # TUNED WORKFLOW FIT
  tune_wflw_fit = wflw_fit_prophet_tuned,
  # FROM FEATURE ENGINEERING
  splits = artifacts$splits,
  data = artifacts$data,
  recipes = artifacts$recipes,
  standardize = artifacts$standardize,
  normalize = artifacts$normalize
)

tuned_prophet %>%
  write_rds("tuned_prophet.rds")


# XGBOOST PARAMETER TUNING ------------------------------------------------

model_spec_xgboost_tune <- boost_tree(
  mode = "regression",
  mtry = tune(),
  trees = tune(),
  min_n = tune()
) %>% 
  set_engine("xgboost")

model_spec_xgboost_tune

wflw_spec_xgboost_tune <- workflow() %>%
  add_model(model_spec_xgboost_tune) %>%
  add_recipe(artifacts$recipes$recipe_spec)

artifacts$recipes$recipe_spec %>%
  # update_role(Month, new_role = "indicator") %>%
  prep() %>%
  summary() %>%
  group_by(role) %>%
  summarise(n = n())

extract_parameter_set_dials(model_spec_xgboost_tune)

# ROUND 1

set.seed(123)
xgboost_grid_spec_1 <- grid_latin_hypercube(
  extract_parameter_set_dials(model_spec_xgboost_tune) %>%
    update(mtry = mtry(range = c(1, 49))),
  size = 20
)

xgboost_grid_spec_1

registerDoFuture()

plan(
  strategy = cluster,
  workers  = parallel::makeCluster(parallel::detectCores())
)

extract_preprocessor(wflw_spec_xgboost_tune)

tic()
tune_results_xgboost_1 <- wflw_spec_xgboost_tune %>%
  tune_grid(
    resamples = resamples_kfold,
    grid = xgboost_grid_spec_1,
    control = control_grid(
      verbose = TRUE,
      allow_par = TRUE
    )
  )
toc()

plan(strategy = sequential)

# tune_results_xgboost_1 %>%
#   show_best("rmse", n = Inf)
#
# tune_results_xgboost_1 %>%
#   show_best("rsq", n = Inf)

xgboost_gr1 <- tune_results_xgboost_1 %>%
  autoplot() +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE)

ggplotly(xgboost_gr1)
```

Comment: I'm currently trying to run the code. Can I suggest making it smaller/quicker for purposes of an example on here?

Comment: I was able to run your code without issue! I might suggest:

* restarting your R session and re-running to ensure that your recipe objects have been generated with your most up-to-date code
* if that doesn't do the trick, ensure your installs of tidymodels are up to date
* if that doesn't do the trick, [provide a reproducible example](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) demonstrating your issue, making sure to remove any code that isn't needed to demonstrate it.

Comment: @SimonCouch Thanks for taking the time to run through this. Just to confirm, the XGB hyperparameter tuning section of the code worked without issue?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that simply adding the step_rm(Month) via a pipe (%>%) to the workflow doesn't suffice, what is needed is an update to the recipe using the update_recipe.

I achieved this by adding the update_recipe to my workflow:

```
wflw_spec_xgboost_tune <- workflow() %>%
  add_model(model_spec_xgboost_tune) %>%
  add_recipe(artifacts$recipes$recipe_spec) %>% 
  update_recipe(artifacts$recipes$recipe_spec %>% step_rm(Month))
```